# nginx resolving localhost on proxy pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server that only responds to localhost.  I cannot change this.  I have submitted two tickets with Microsoft.  As a stopgap I downloaded nginx for Windows.  This used to work but for some reason it stopped working.

I think the issue is because nginx is resolving to http://127.0.0.1.  It should be quite obvious that wouldn't fly in most situations.  I point it to other sites and it works, but if I pointed it to example.org and it redirect to http://1.1.1.1 example.org may not be configured to respond to that.

```
http {

    server {
        listen       41281;
        
        location / {
                #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                #proxy_set_header Host $host;
                #proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
                #proxy_redirect http://localhost:5000/ http://$server_name/;
        }
    }
```

I've tried both what's commented out and the way it is right now.

error.log says:

```
2020/08/07 22:05:10 [error] 26908#22324: *1 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.29, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "192.168.0.29:41281"
```

and the browser/curl gets 502.

```
$ curl localhost:5000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3024  100  3024    0     0   246k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  268k<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 ...
```

```
jbaro@ezio MINGW64 ~
$ curl 127.0.0.1:5000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
```

```
jbaro@ezio MINGW64 ~
$ curl localhost:41281
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   157  100   157    0     0     71      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    71<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

502 - means that you upstream/backend is not response, is a normal response for nginx if backend is down.

In you example for `curl 127.0.0.1:5000`:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000
```

Check you backend app on the 5000/tcp port. May be this app is not binding on the localhost IP / 5000/tcp port, or not running.

Netstat for windows cmd:

```
netstat -np TCP | findstr 5000
```