# Vhost docker website resolves with port at the end but nginx 502 error without it (recv failed Connection reset by peer)

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, vhosts

It's an email server that everyone else seems to be getting running [with the same settings](https://github.com/knadh/listmonk/issues/1590#issuecomment-1812399067). For some reason it's not working for me, and none of the previous answers for "*502 nginx docker*" or "*recv failed Connection reset by peer*" have solved it. Maybe it has to do with [my Nginx Vhost setup](https://centminmod.com/nginx_domain_dns_setup.html)?

The site loads properly on serverIP:5870 and if I change `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5870;` to `proxy_pass http://example.com:5870;` then it will load on example.com:5870. But it gives the 502 error when I visit the site without the port.

If I set `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5870;` and visit example.com:5870 I get:

```
The connection for this site is not secure
example.com sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

If I change proxy_pass to `http://example.com:5870;` example.com will load, but a "broken" page with basic text and the urls are http://localhost:9000/subscription/form".

[Broken listmonk homepage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIy4A.jpg)

#### docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

x-app-defaults: &amp;app-defaults
  restart: unless-stopped
  image: listmonk/listmonk:latest
  ports:
    - "5870:9000"
  networks:
    - listmonk
  environment:
    - TZ=Etc/UTC

x-db-defaults: &amp;db-defaults
  image: postgres:13
  ports:
    - "9432:5432"
  networks:
    - listmonk
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pw
    - POSTGRES_USER=listmonk
    - POSTGRES_DB=listmonk
  restart: unless-stopped
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U listmonk"]
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 6

services:
  db:
    &lt;&lt;: *db-defaults
    container_name: listmonk_db
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: listmonk-data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    &lt;&lt;: *app-defaults
    container_name: listmonk_app
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./config.toml:/listmonk/config.toml
      - ./uploads:/listmonk/uploads

networks:
  listmonk:

volumes:
  listmonk-data:
```

#### nginx config:

```
server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name            example.com;

  location / {
     proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5870;
     proxy_set_header   Host            $http_host;
     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    }

}

server {
    listen              80;
    server_name            example.com;
      location / {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
}
```

The nginx error log shows `2023/11/22 17:54:00 [error] 54579#54579: *2 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: <myip>, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5870/", host: "example.com"`

Search results for "*recv failed 104 Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream*" all say it's a php-fpm issue. But I haven't found any solutions. php-fpm:

```
sudo netstat -nlpt |grep 9000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1175/php-fpm: maste
```

I've tried many variations of `proxy_pass`:

- `proxy_pass http://example.com:5870;`
- `proxy_pass http://<SERVER_IP>:5870;` - same result as above.
- `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5870;` same as 127.0.0.1:5870.
- `proxy_pass http://example.com/;` results in "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".
- `proxy_pass http://listmonk_app:5870;`, `proxy_pass http://app:5870;`, and `proxy_pass http://listmonk:5870;` all cause [nginx errors](https://lemmy.world/comment/5586470).

I found this [nginx resolving localhost on proxy pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311201/nginx-resolving-localhost-on-proxy-pass) and ran:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5870
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

curl 0.0.0.0:5870
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

curl 127.0.0.1:9000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                  PORTS                                       NAMES
6738da252977   listmonk/listmonk:latest   "./listmonk"             3 weeks ago   Up 47 hours             0.0.0.0:5870->9000/tcp, :::5870->9000/tcp   listmonk_app
f8d43916e568   postgres:13                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 weeks ago   Up 47 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:9432->5432/tcp, :::9432->5432/tcp   listmonk_db

sudo netstat -nlpt |grep 5870
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5870            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2757/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5870                 :::*                    LISTEN      2762/docker-proxy
```

I tried some of the solutions here https://serverfault.com/questions/351212/nginx-redirects-to-port-8080-when-accessing-url-without-slash

`proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` didn't seem to change anything.

I also tried

```
  proxy_pass http://example.com:5870/;
  proxy_redirect http://example.com:5870/ http://example.com/;
```

Maybe this [NodeJs on nginx not working without a port number in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097334/nodejs-on-nginx-not-working-without-a-port-number-in-the-url) is the answer, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a firewall issue. I disabled my firewall and it works.